# SSRS 2008 - Sorting within a group

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, sorting, reporting-services, grouping

I am using SSRS 2008 with a tablix control that has one Row Group defined (called MyGroup).  Can someone please explain the difference between the following sorting options you can pick from?

1. Sorting via the Tablix properties window
2. Sorting via the MyGroup (a row group I created) properties window
3. Sorting via the Details (default child row group of MyGroup) properties window.

Does sorting at the Tablix level do an initial sorting.... which is later refined by the sorting you can define inside your Group.....  which is later refined by any sorting defined inside the Details (default group)?

It's a little confusing how you could potentially navigate to all of the properties dialogs mentioned above and define sorting differently in each of these locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, yes:

- Sorting via the Tablix properties window sets the initial sort order of the Tablix.
- Sorting via the Group properties window will override the Tablix sort order for sorting groups, but will retain the Tablix sort order within groups.
- Sorting via the Details properties window will override the Tablix sort order for sorting within groups.