# SRSS: Group-Sorting gets ignored

Tags: reporting-services

if you have a look on this link [SSRS 2008 - Sorting within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008670/ssrs-2008-sorting-within-a-group) it should be possible to sort at a Tablix and overwrite this behavior on the Grouping.
So my structure is basically: Tablix --> Grouping --> Details Group

In the Grouping, I want to sort (and group ofc) at the PbiID ascending, but the Items without PBI-Number or Number = 0 should come last.

So before I sort to PBINr I added another sorting expression at the Group:

```
=
switch(
Fields!PBINr.Value is nothing, 2,
Fields!PBINr.Value = 0, 1,
1 = 1, 1)
```

I even tried some strange stuff like:

```
=
switch(
Fields!PBINr.Value is nothing, "zzzzzzzzz",
Fields!PBINr.Value = 0, "yyyyyyy",
1 = 1, "aaaaaa")
```

But nothing seems to work. So is the sorting itself wrong or can't I sort at the Grouping?

Thanks in advance.

Matthias

Comment: Couple of things... Is there any sorting at the Tablix or Details Group that is confusing things? Secondly, if you are checking for NULL values I would use `IsNothing(Fields!PBINr.Value)` instead of what you have above.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the IsNothing, sadly it didnt change anything. Since the order is still NULL,0, PBIIds, I guess my sorting gets ignored at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ian the correct syntax is: `IsNothing(Fields!PBINr.Value)`

But I also suspect you need to move that sort expression to the Details group.  Otherwise it will only look at the value from the first record in the group.

Comment: IsNothing did not help. So If I get this right: If I create an Ordering on a Grouping, I cant order at something else than the Grouping Property itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "something else"? What do you mean by "the Grouping Property"?

Comment: Example: I group by PBINr, can't I order this grouping on anything else than PBINr, F.E. PBISortingNumber (A field which I calculate)?

Comment: You can sort on anything relevant to that group - there is a separate Sorting page in the Group Properties.  It defaults to your Group Expression, but you can edit it.

Comment: So do you have any Ideas how it keeps sorting the ID 0 at first and not as last as shown in the Initial post?

Comment: I suspect your first test inside your Switch function is never tru, due to incorrect syntax. Then the IsNothing() rows would fall through to the last clause and get a value of 1, same as the ID 0 rows.  I would add a textbox to the group and put the Switch expression into it to debug.